# Visual Studio Code Chrome Debugger - Error on starting to debug

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, chrome-remote-debugging

When Starting the chrome debugger inside of visual studio code, it shows a popup with an error stating "Cannot find debug adapter for type 'chrome'."

I have already tried setting the remote-debugging-port to 9222 in the properties of Chrome as well as in the launch.json

Here is the launch.json that I'm currently trying to use:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Chrome Debug",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/app",
            "runtimeArgs" : [
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
            ],
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/path_to_js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I uninstalled and reinstalled the Debugger for Chrome extension and restarted VS Code. It started working.

Comment: Just restarting VSCode worked for me. 
My session had regressed to a state where several features weren't working (git lens wasn't showing commit details, the Source Control tab native to VSC wasn't sensing the local repo), so it's not a surprise that the chrome debugger extension was also malfunctioning. 
I suppose there's a reason why IT pros usually ask, "have you turned it off and back on again?"